# how to return to original buffer after py-execute-region

Tags: python, emacs, elisp, ipython

I more or less set up ipython working with emacs. However, there is still something not very handy. Every time i select a region from my script buffer and do py-execute-region, after the execution, the cursor STAYS in the *PYTHON* buffer, rather than returning to my script buffer. 
Then i have to do a C-x o to move the cursor back to my script and keep writing things.

Is there an option/fix that lets py-execute-buffer return to original buffer after execution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know that mode, but as a *quick fix* I can think of something like this:

```
(defun my-py-execute-region()
  (interactive)
  (py-execute-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (other-window 1))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m") (lambda () (interactive) (my-py-execute-region)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check customization of py-switch-buffers-on-execute-p, it defaults to nil, but seems `t' there.

By default the output buffer is displayed, but not selected.